# Using Android UX SDK and Mobile SDK at same time

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I've been using the Mobile SDK tutorial at

[DJI Mobile SDK Tutorial](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration)

and I got that to work.

I've since starting trying to integrate in the UX SDK into this project (this is to the original app I built above). I am following this:

[DJI UX SDK Tutorial](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/ux_sdk_introduction.html)

to do that.

I've included both sdk's in the gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dji.ImportSDKDemo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true  // allows debug version to be bigger than allowed
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true  // release version will go through shrinking process
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"

        pickFirst 'lib/*/libstlport_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libRoadLineRebuildAPI.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviUtils.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviMapex.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviData.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviMap.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviSearch.so'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  // allows debug version to be bigger than allowed

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    /*
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    */
    implementation 'com.amap.api:map2d:5.2.0'
    implementation 'com.amap.api:3dmap:5.5.0'
    implementation 'com.amap.api:search:5.5.0'
    implementation 'com.amap.api:location:3.6.1'
    //implementation files('libs/HERE-sdk-3.8.0.aar')  // HERE maps

    implementation ('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.9')
    implementation ('com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.9')
    compileOnly ('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.9')
}
```

I haven't started to use any of the calls from the UX SDK, just wanted to see if it would build and install. It does build and install on the Android devce, but no longer registers. I get the following on the app

> "Register sdk fails"

The package name and applicationId were not changed (they are the same in both build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml).

Is this because I am trying to load both SDK's? If so, do I need both SDK's?  If all the functionality is one or the other, I would just use one.

I then regenerated an APP ID to use wit this particular app, but that did not help.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use UXSDK in your project, no need to import "implementation ('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.9')" in the build.gradle file.

For registration issue, please double check if you use the same package name in the `package` value of the **AndroidManifest.xml** file (On top of the file) and the `applicationId` value of the **build.gradle** file. Also check the network connection of your mobile device.

As I saw the code you posted, you use "com.dji.ImportSDKDemo" in your build.gradle file. Then double check if you register the App Key using this package name on DJI developer website.

If you want to learn how to integrate UXSDK to your project, please check this tutorial: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/UXSDKDemo.html

Answer (score 0):

See the UX example, it already includes the SDK.  The build.gradle has the following:

```
implementation('com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.9', {
    // Uncomment the following line if your app does not need Anti Distortion for
    // Mavic 2 Pro and Mavic 2 Zoom. It will greatly reducing the size of the APK:
    // exclude module: 'library-anti-distortion'
})

compileOnly('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.9')
```

Don't forget changes to the manifest; again, you can copy the information from the sample.